# Is there a max number of containers that can connect to a network simultaneously?

Tags: docker, containers

I am trying to operate a machine to run many Docker containers. The potential number of concurrent containers is in the hundreds. All these containers connect to the same bridge network.

I wonder if this will run into some issues. Like, is there a max number of containers that can connect to a network simultaneously? What would happen if I ran into that limit?

Comment: Seems like simply trying it out and seeing what happens might be the fastest way to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can have containers for the number of IPs you define in the network. For example i create a network with this command:
`docker network create —attachable -d overlay —subnet=10.2.0.0/16` 
So i can have 65,536 containers according to my system capacity :)